# To prove this associative statement about spectral theory

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Show that $\sigma(AB) \cup \{0\} = \sigma(BA) \cup \{0\}$ in general, and that $\sigma(AB) = \sigma(BA)$ if $A$ is bijective.

I studied the associative statement of this somewhere but it did not include the zeroth element. 
If you assume the bijection, how can you show the first part?

### My attempt

Let show that $A$ commutes with $B$ which is self-adjoint linear operatar such that $AB = BA$. 
\begin{equation*}
AB = A^{\ast} B^{\ast} = (BA)^{\ast} = (ABA)^{\ast} = A^{\ast} B^{\ast} A^{\ast} = ABA = BA.
\end{equation*}
In general, the zeroth element follows directly in the left-hand-side if $A$ is bijective. $\square$

Comments

- not sure if $\sigma$ should be carried along; I was reading Kreuzig for the application

---

How can you show the first part with the zeroth element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in \sigma(AB)$, $\lambda \ne 0$ be given. Then, $AB - \lambda \, I$ is (boundedly) invertible. By a simple calculation, you can verify
$$(BA - \lambda)^{-1} = \lambda^{-1} \, \Big(I - B \,(AB-\lambda)^{-1} \, A\Big),$$
see also the [Sherman–Morrison-Woodbury formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula). Hence, $\lambda \in \sigma(BA)$. This shows the first claim.

For the case that $A$ is invertible, you can use the argument by Martin Argerami.

Answer (score 2):

*I cannot understand what you are trying to do in your attempt.*

If $A$ is a bijective operator between Banach spaces, then $A$ is invertible. Now
$$
AB=A(BA)A^{-1},
$$
and
$$
AB-\lambda I=A(BA-\lambda I)A^{-1}.
$$
So $AB-\lambda I$ is invertible precisely when $BA-\lambda$ is, which shows that the resolvent of $AB$ equals to that of $BA$. Thus, $\sigma(AB)=\sigma(BA)$.